# android dexed lib is empty

Tags: java, android

I use VkontakteSDK-lib and it was(!) ok. 
It is project imported in workspace(Eclipse) and included in my project. 
But now on launching this lib has size 166 bytes in dexedLibs (only META-INF inside).
And of course i have in log:

```
  Could not find class 'com.perm.kate.api.Api' referenced from method com.<my_package_path>.VKController.<init>
```

I tried copy lib from /bin and include her in my project directly (size = 86.6kb), but it still to resize to 166 bytes on bin/dexedLibs folder...

Because of what it could be?

**Solved**

I deleted directly jar lib, removed from workspace lib project,clear my project, manually delete dexed lib from "dexedLibs" this jar (166 bytes) and again import lib project and include in my project. Again it is happiness.

Comment: Glad you solved your own problem, but rather than editing your solution into your question, please post it as an answer and accept it, so that the site software realizes the question has been resolved. Otherwise it will be periodically churned to the top of the active question queue for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I deleted directly jar lib, removed from workspace lib project,clear my project, manually delete dexed lib from "dexedLibs" this jar (166 bytes) and again import lib project and include in my project. Again it is happiness.